# How to accept personal certificate using selenium java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, autoit

We are trying to load a client URL and it is must to accept the personal certificate installed in my local machine. I am using robot keys to click on 'OK' button on the certificate popup. By the time it is clicking on 'Ok' button i am experiencing session timeout and the script is failing. I have also tried to reduce the implicit time.

Is there a way to solve the issue by setting chrome capabilities to select the personal certificate based on the name of the certificate(I have Multiple certificates based on the user) during the driver initialization.

Answer (score 0):

For accepting alert you could use below code :

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       
caps.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (caps);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this at driver initialization level.

Code :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability(capabilityName, value);
//options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(acceptInsecureCerts)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```